# How to request more than one resource in SimPy

Tags: python, simpy

I would like to have processes requesting more than one resource from the shared resources pool.

For instance, with this code I can only request one resource:

```
def job(pool, total_requested):
    with pool.request() as request:
        yield request

if __name__ == "__main__":
    env = simpy.Environment()
    pool = simpy.Resource(env, RESOURCES)
    env.process(job(pool, 5))
    env.run()
```

What if I would like to allocate 5 together.

Is there any other function for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use `Environment.all_of()`

http://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/events.html#waiting-for-multiple-events-at-once

Comment: Using that the process would be given resources when they are available, but not all of them at the same time. Because of that, resources would be allocated without being used while waiting for the rest of them.

Comment: True, but there’s currently no other way if you don't want to implement your own resource type.